# I can't seem to divide NSUInteger by 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuinteger

The snippet of code:

```
NSUInteger *lengthOfLine =100;
NSUInteger *half = lengthOfLine/2;
```

The compile error for line 2:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned long *') and 'int')
```

Comment: Get rid of the asterisk. You don't want a pointer.

Comment: @rmaddy : mind blowing!! It works. Thanks. Please post as reply so I may mark as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `NSUInteger`, not `NSUInteger *`. `NSUInteger` is a primitive type, not a subclass of `NSObject`. Now you're dealing with a pointer to `NSUInteger`